# How to automatically add new row in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace, automation

I want to automatically add row in Google Spreadsheets when I type information in row 5 by Google script.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tznfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your answer by the technical side, code isn't indexed by the social side more people could understand your answer if you describe it and explain how to use it. Ref. [answer]